# Como solucionar los permisos para npm en windows 10

Tags: nodejs, npm, windows10, permisos

Utilizo Windows 10 y a través de cmeder utilice el siguiente comando `npm doctor` el cual verifica el estado de instalación de npm y si hay algún problema en ella y el resultado que obtuve fue el siguiente

```
    λ npm doctor
npm notice PING https://registry.npmjs.org/
Check                               Value                        Recommendationnpm ping                            ok
npm -v                              v6.14.5                      Use npm v6.14.9
node -v                             v12.18.1                     Use node v14.15.1
npm config get registry             https://registry.npmjs.org/
which git                           not installed                Install git and ensure it's in your PATH.
Perms check on cached files         notOk                        Check the permissions of your files in C:\Users\Oficina-QA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
Perms check on global node_modules  notOk                        C:\Users\Oficina-QA\AppData\Roaming\npm\lib\node_modules must be readable and writable by the current user.
Perms check on local node_modules   notOk                        C:\Windows\System32\node_modules must be readable and writable by the current user.
Verify cache contents               notOk
```

Investigando un poco me encontré con que es un problemas de permisos de usuarios, usualmente sucede en linux al utilizar npm como `root` o porque se han realizado instalaciones con `sudo npm`.
Si alguien pudiera indicar como solucionar esto en windows 10.

Comment: Ya lo intentaste hacer desde cmd?

Comment: Si, inclusive desde la powershell y siendo admin. Desinstalare y probare actualizare la version de node y NPM para ver que resulta.